# Adding rows to a dataframe with pre-allocated memory?

Tags: julia

Let's say I have a **pre-sized** dataframe and I want to assign values to every row. (Therfore *push!* and *append!* are out of game)

```
length = 10
df = DataFrame(id = Array(Int64,length),value = Array(String,length))

for n in 1:10
             df[n,:id] = n
             df[n,:value] = "random text"
end
```

The above code shows how to do that cell by cell for each iterated row.

Is there a solution to add an **entire row at once** for each iteration?
Because

```
for n in 1:10
             df[n] = [n "random text"]
end
```

throws a wrong type exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a row the syntax is `[row,:]` rather than just row.

Also you'll need to convert the row to a DataFrame first.

```
for n in 1:10
    df[n,:] = DataFrame([n "random text2"])
end
```

Comment: When using this solution, one needs to be careful about the column ordering in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You can roll your own function to set a row quite easily:

```
julia> function setrow!(df, rowi, val)                                                                                                      
           for j in eachindex(val)  
               df[rowi, j] = val[j] 
           end                      
           df                                                                                                                       
       end                          
setrow! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> setrow!(df, 1, [1, "a"])
10×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ id              │ value    │
├─────┼─────────────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 1               │ "a"      │
│ 2   │ 140525709817424 │ "#undef" │
│ 3   │ 140525709817488 │ "#undef" │
│ 4   │ 140525709817072 │ "#undef" │
│ 5   │ 140525709817104 │ "#undef" │
│ 6   │ 140525709817136 │ "#undef" │
│ 7   │ 140525709817168 │ "#undef" │
│ 8   │ 140525709817200 │ "#undef" │
│ 9   │ 140525709817232 │ "#undef" │
│ 10  │ 0               │ "#undef" │
```

Ideally, you might be able to use the broadcasting assignment syntax:

```
df[2, :] .= [2, "b"]
```

But that appears to be not implemented (perhaps for good reason, I'm not sure).